# Traffic not set for newly create App Engine by Terraform (standard app version)

Tags: google-app-engine, terraform

I can deploy my App Engine app without problems by `gcloud app deploy` command

With Terraform, deploy successfully but traffic allocation is 0%

I search official of Terraform for App Engine - standard app version, but it seems no option for setting traffic. If you know how to set this, please tell me.
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/app_engine_standard_app_version

My main.tf code

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "<= 3.49"
    }
  }
}
provider "google" {
  project = "{my-project}"
  credentials = "{my-service-account-key.json}"
  zone = "asia-northeast1-a"
}

resource "random_string" "random" {
  length            = 16
  upper             = false
  special           = false
  # override_special = "/@£$"
}

output "version_id" {
      value = random_string.random.id
    }

resource "google_app_engine_standard_app_version" "default" {
    version_id = random_string.random.id
    project = "{my-project}"
    service = "default"
    runtime = "nodejs16"
    instance_class = "F4_1G"

    deployment {
        zip {
            source_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/{my-bucket}/source.zip"
        }
    }

    entrypoint {
      shell = "yarn install && yarn start"
    }
    delete_service_on_destroy = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [google_app_engine_service_split_traffic](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/app_engine_service_split_traffic) resource to manage traffic.

```
resource "google_app_engine_service_split_traffic" "default" {
  service = google_app_engine_standard_app_version.default.service
  migrate_traffic = true

  split {
    shard_by = "IP"
    allocations = {
      (google_app_engine_standard_app_version.default.version_id) = 1.0
    }
  }
}
```